# Can we adjust subtitle size and position in YouTube app?

Tags: youtube

Using Android 13 in Pixel 7.

Is there any way we can change the font size or placement of subtitles of a running video within the YouTube app without any subscription model? Is that feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The subtitle size can be set from the device settings for captions.**

From [YouTube Help - Manage subtitle settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/100078?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cchange-default-size-style-of-captions)

> Change default size & style of captions
>
> 1. Tap your profile picture [image].
> 2. Tap **Settings** [image].
> 3. Tap **Captions**.
> 4. Tap “**Caption size and style**” to change the default size and font.

**The subtitle position cannot be configured from the YouTube app.** However, there may be alternative options like:

1. For devices that have [Live Caption](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9350862), system-generated captions can be moved along vertically (thanks to [a YouTube video by Kris Occhipinti](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur-xrn-Ufgk).

   > #### Move the caption box
   >
   > **To move the caption box:** Touch and hold, then drag up or down.

(Note that the YouTube Premium subscription doesn't provide additional settings for subtitles/captions)